# Unique code based on districts

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a unique code to every user registering. The thing is that the unique code needs to be generated based on which city the user is from.
So the tables I have are:

```
CREATE TABLE `microreg`.`users` ( `user_id` INT NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT , `user_code` CHAR(10) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
UNIQUE (`user_code`));
```

`user_id` is for unique identification of users in DB.
 
 `user_code` is
   the readable code generated for the use of users. They access their
   account with that unique code.

```
CREATE TABLE `microreg`.`districts` ( `district_id` INT NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT , `district_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `district_code`
CHAR(4) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`district_id`), UNIQUE (`district_code`));`
```

This contains as about 20K districts with unique code assigned.

say,

```
Trichy      ITRY
Coimbatore  ICBE
Kolkata     IKOL
Delhi       IDEL
...
New York    UNYK
Washington  UWDC
```

So, when user registers with Trichy as district, he will be generated with

```
user_id   : 1
user_code : ITRY000001
```

second user from same city

```
user_id   : 2
user_code : ITRY000002
```

another one from New York

```
user_id   : 3
user_code : UNYK000001
```

user_code is unique with respect to district. [User with id 1 and 3 are not same]

So far, I fetched the maximum value of the selected district of the user

```
SELECT RIGHT(MAX(user_code),6) FROM `users` WHERE user_code LIKE 'ITRY%';
```

and then increment it by 1 and then add it back with district_code appended to it.

```
INSERT INTO `microreg`.`users` (`user_id`, `user_code`) VALUES (NULL, 'ITRY000003');
```

This method works perfectly when there is only one user updating at a time. But this started creating problem when multiple users concurrently started registering. 
Since unique is set, two users with same user_code was generated and creates overhead.

Previously, for another application, I created unique tables for every code (like district here) and added the user to that table and then appended back to original table (like users here).
In that case I had only 4 types of code (like district here). But for this app, I have got about 20K districts. I couldn't get a spark for this. (For information, I use PHP with mysqli for this application) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `uniqid()` with a prefix for the town? Like so:

```
 $user_code = uniqid('UNYK', true); // with more entropy that is
```

Be aware though that this is not a 100% unique and somewhat predictable (I guess not for a "normal" purpose).

Alternatively (according to your comment), you could set up a new table (say `towntoid` or sth.) with three columns

```
Town        town_code  current_max
----------|-----------|-----------
Trichy      ITRY        10
Coimbatore  ICBE        124
Kolkata     IKOL        213
Delhi       IDEL        0
...
New York    UNYK        21
```

Fetch the `current_max` from there and increment it by one if a new user registers. The tables could be connected via JOIN (on town_code).

Comment: This creates a unique identifier, but the need actually differs, to increment the user_code based on previous code from same district. A sort of Auto-increment with multiple prefixes

Comment: Whaa.. that appears simple!

Comment: @VijayaSankarN: The simple solutions tend to be the best :-)

Comment: absolutely! let me mark accepted if this works perfect! working with this, checking if there is a workaround to reduce the number of requests to DB.

Comment: Oops! Same problem, two people fetching the current_max, both increments by one and clash again!

Comment: @VijayaSankarN What is your actual query? Did you join it on the newly created table and select the current_max from there?

Comment: Nope, i selected the current max from the table, incremented by 1 and then inserted into users table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93603/discussion-between-vijaya-sankar-n-and-jan).